# How to pass parameter to source command in mysql .The parameter is set before to file path

Tags: mysql

I am tring to import sql file from command prompt. where i use source command and the file path is set into one varible :

```
set @path='/home/xxx/Downloads/database script/adverise.sql';
source @path
```

And the error is

```
ERROR: Failed to open file '@path', error: 2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below command, you don't need to put the store into a variable and then use it.

```
source /home/xxx/Downloads/database script/adverise.sql
```

If you still need to store the path in a variable then store it into a variable but you can also pass the same path with "source /path/to/file" so that both scenarios will handle.

Comment: The @path required in advertise.sql file to import some more files , i checked with your solution but not solve my problem .

Comment: Where ever you are using "source " you have to use the hardcoded path, I tried many solutions but it seems something is missing. If you have @path in "advertise.sql" then you need to replace them too. Or you can pass this parameter with "mysql" command only.

Comment: To solve this problem is any alternate solution so i can pass parameter when import the file.

Comment: This is not working, please give any alternate solution